# How to reproduce the following stereometry problem with pst-solides3d?

Tags: pstricks, pst-solides3d

I am interested in reproducing the following diagram with PSTricks' 3D package named `pst-solides3d`.
Unfortunately I am not familiar with the package and I am not sure whether or not it supports

- translation
- intersection

Could you show me how to reproduce the following with `pst-solides3d`?

<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>I am a sort of person who can't be bothered to read documentation even after wrong things have happened. This is my learning style.</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>

```
\documentclass[pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

% P on BCGF
% Q on ADHE
% Draw the intersection point S between PQ and BCHE

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-1,-1)(10.5,11)
    % A cube
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={180,0,-60,180}](0,0){A}(6,0){B}(9,3){C}(3,3){D}(0,6){E}
    \pstTranslation[PosAngle={0,-45,180}]{A}{E}{B,C,D}[F,G,H]
    \psline(E)(H)(G)(C)(B)(F)(E)(A)(B)
    \psline(F)(G)
    \psline[linestyle=dashed](H)(D)(C)
    \psline[linestyle=dashed](A)(D)
    
    
    % P and Q
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={0,180}](9.5,2){P}(1,9.5){Q}
    

    % Hidden Qt by translating Q along HQ
    \pstTranslation[PointName=none,PointSymbol=none]{H}{D}{Q}[Qt]
    % Hidden Pt by translating P along CG
    \pstTranslation[PointName=none,PointSymbol=none]{C}{G}{P}[Pt]
    
    
    % Q' = intersection QQt and EH
    \pstInterLL[PosAngle=180]{Q}{Qt}{E}{H}{Q'}
    % Q'' = intersection QQt and AD
    \pstInterLL[PosAngle=160]{Q}{Qt}{A}{D}{Q''}
    
    % P' = intersection PPt and FG
    \pstInterLL[PosAngle=0]{P}{Pt}{F}{G}{P'}
    % P'' = intersection PPt and BC
    \pstInterLL[PosAngle=0]{P}{Pt}{B}{C}{P''}


  % auxiliary lines
    \pcline[linecolor=lightgray,nodesepB=-1](G)(P')
    \pcline[linecolor=lightgray,nodesepB=-1](C)(P'')
    \pcline[linecolor=lightgray,nodesep=-1](P')(P)
        
    \pcline[linecolor=lightgray,nodesepB=-1](Q')(Q)
    \pcline[linecolor=lightgray,nodesepB=-1,linestyle=dashed](Q')(Q'')

    
    % plane BCHE
    \pspolygon[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow,opacity=0.2](B)(C)(H)(E)
    % plane Q'Q''P''P'
    \pspolygon[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green,opacity=0.2](Q')(Q'')(P'')(P')
    
    
    % common line between two planes
    \psline[linecolor=red,linestyle=dashed](Q')(P'')    
    
    % PQ
    \psline[linecolor=blue,linestyle=dashed](P)(Q)
    
    % intersection point between PQ and the common line
    \pstInterLL[PosAngle=45]{P}{Q}{Q'}{P''}{S}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It makes no real sense to use `pst-solides 3d` for this example, because you do not have hidden surfaces. Use simple 2d or 3d (`pst-3dplot`) with opacity option to show it.

Comment: @user187802: Using `pst-3dplot` is really hard. It does not provide us with nodes in 3D points `(x,y,z)`, there is no macro to find intersection between 2 lines, projecting a point on a line, and many more. :-(